# PEAR Mail script seems to hang and cannot debug it

Tags: php, email, pear

I am having a very similar problem posed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284468/problem-with-php-pear-mail), unfortunately the answers in that thread have not helped me.

Nothing seems to run after the `$mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);`.

None of the echo statements or the error checks after output anything, its as though when the script reaches the `Mail::factory` line the script just stops.

The script itself returns a HTTP 200, though the mail is not sent or any sent/not sent responses the script generates is returned.

I have tried uninstalling/re-installing the PEAR Mail, Net and Auth libraries and the problem still persists.

I also tried running the script on the server directly from the command line,

It's as though once the `Mail::factory` called is made the script stops processing anymore, no errors are returned so I have no clue where to start looking to get this fixed.

I have also run the script directly on the server through the PHP CLI:
It outputs everything until the `Mail::factory` call and nothing after.

> D:\Parallels\Additional\PleskPHP5>php phpmailcheck.php
>
> PEAR is installed!
>
> PEAR Mail is installed!
>
> going to call Mail::factory
>
> D:\Parallels\Additional\PleskPHP5>

I have also checked the sites error logs and there are no errors reported.

UPDATE:
I have tried adding the following just before the `Mail::factory` call: `echo(Mail::factory('smtp', $params));`
which from the pear mail documentation says it should return an object or an error message.
the script seems to end on this line without echoing anything...

```
<?php
require_once('D:\Parallels\Additional\PleskPHP5\Pear\System.php');
require_once "Mail.php";
if(class_exists('System')===true) {
    echo '<p>PEAR is installed!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>PEAR is not installed!</p>';
}
if(class_exists('Mail')===true) {
    echo '<p>PEAR Mail is installed!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>PEAR Mail is not installed!</p>';
}

//start mail
$from = "My Website <webmailer@website.co.uk>";
$to = "Website Owner <email@emailaddress.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?<br>This is a test email for pear";

$host = "mail.mailserver.co.uk";
$port = 25;
$username = "website@website.co.uk";
$password = "password";

$params = array('host'=>$host,'port'=>$port,'auth'=>true,'username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
$headers = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);


echo('going to call Mail::factory'); //echos out correctly
$mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

echo('just called Mail::factory'); // does not echo

$mail->send($to,$headers,$message);
//$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
?>
```

Comment: are you sure it hangs? Perhaps it's simply dying. have you checked the server error logs and/or turned on display_errors/error_reporting?

Comment: the output from php cli is: D:\Parallels\Additional\PleskPHP5>php phpmailcheck.php
<p>PEAR is installed!</p>
<p>PEAR Mail is installed!</p>
going to call Mail::factory
D:\Parallels\Additional\PleskPHP5>
so nothing after the mailfactory seems to be processed i have error_reporting(E_ALL); set

Comment: sorry, @halfer there is one instance where i have failed to capitalize the class-name `Mail` though thanks for your valued input, its been most helpful.

Comment: No problem @Dizzy, this place can offer a baptism of fire sometimes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the exit status:

```
$ php mailcheck.php; echo $?
```

or on windows:

```
$ php mailcheck.php
$ echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
```

It will be > 0 if there was a fatal error within the php code.

Then make sure you have `display_errors` on and `error_reporting` set to the correct level. If you don't, you won't see any output. If you have xdebug installed, enable `xdebug.scream`.

---

Since you have exit code 255, there is something broken with your php files.

First, use `ini_set` to set display_errors to 1 and error_reporting to E_ALL. Run the code again.

---

If that does not hepl make sure the code is syntactically correct by running

```
$ php -l path/to/file.php
```

It will tell you when there is a syntax error. Do this for all files.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, am having trouble trying to get this to run on a windows machine through the cli, i have run two seperate commands `php phpmailcheck.php` then `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%` which returns `exitcode is 255`

Comment: am gussing there is a fatal error as the exit code is 255, i cant install xdebug on the server, so how do i go about tracking down this error?

Comment: I've had display errors set to 1 and error reporting set to E_All, still no errors reported the script just seems to terminate at the mail::factory call, am begining to think its a problem with the pear instalation instead, i am going to see if i can get the script to work on a shared hosted server, if that does then its a problem with  server and not the script, thanks for your help

Comment: seems i am getting closer to the problem, i am now getting an error:
`PHP Object of class PHP_Mail could not be converted to string on line 36`, which is this line `$mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);`

Comment: well ive marked this as correct, as it helped me get to the source of the problem, in the end i did a re-install of pear which seems to have fixed the issue.