# PHP Pear Mail: Failing to load Net Classes

Tags: php, email, pear

I've installed PEAR Mail in my server. I have the files:

```
/Mail/smtp.php
```

With the following line 348:

```
include_once ('Net/SMTP.php');
```

And I also have the file:

```
/Net/SMTP.php
```

When I run myscript.php which calls the above files, I get the following error:

```
Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 348
```

I tried changing line 348 above to:

```
include_once ('../Net/SMTP.php');
```

Because `/Net` and `/Mail` directories are side-by-side.

I know others had [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284468/problem-with-php-pear-mail) but couldn't find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once ('/Net/SMTP.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/mysite/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 348

This means that the Net_SMTP is not installed
Just install it by

pear install Net_SMTP

And try to run the code.

Comment: But I do have the file /Net/SMTP.php

Comment: I get: pear/Net_SMTP is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.2
install failed

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to hardcode the full path to the file...

Why is the script not accepting the relative path, I don't know.